# What does Islam say about receiving oral sex between unmarried couples? What about same gender?

Tags: practical-islam, sharia, homosexuality, sexuality

I want to ask you about some questions me and my friends were arguing about.

What is the Islam opinion about receiving oral sex (opposite sex) not married?

Also, what is the Islam opinion about receiving oral sex from ( same sex) do it count as sodomy or obscene?

Comment: You want to know whether or is Haram? Even touching the opposite gender is Haram and you don't whether this is?

Answer (score 1):

Any physical relationship with a non mahram outside of marriage is prohibited. Hence, Oral Sex is too not allowed.

Also none of the Abrahamian religions including Islam allow same sex relationships. Hence, that too is Haram.